# Copy file to backup directory preserving folder structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have to copy a file in a directory, to its backup directory, preserving the folder structure. E.g. the file `aaa` in `MyFolder/Test/aaa` to `.MyFolder.bck/Test/aaa`

I tried to use

```
cp --parents MyFolder/Test/aaa .MyFolder.bck;
```

But the result is `.MyFolder.bck/MyFolder/Test/aaa` and not `.MyFolder.bck/Test/aaa` (which is the one I want).

Comment: [Duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/502478/copy-file-to-backup-directory-preserving-folder-structure)

Comment: [another duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83593/37153)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cd` to the directory and then copy the file:

```
(cd MyFolder && cp --parents Test/aaa ../.MyFolder.bck)
```

The brackets around the command make it run in a subshell, rather than in your current shell. The advantage of this is that it saves you from having to `cd` back to the original directory afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I had this, but I couldn't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two commands?

```
cd MyFolder && cp --parents /Test/aaa .MyFolder.bck;
```

And there are several synchronization utilities for Linux too, even for backup purposes, e.g. rsync, rdiff-backup, synkron... Not to mention the advantages of a local VCS... You should not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use "rsync" for this.

rsync -av MyFolder/ .MyFolder.bck/

Make sure to use the trailing slashes, since they tell rsync that both of these arguments are the "top level" directories (that is, don't create another MyFolder inside of .MyFolder.bck).