# copy files while preserving directory structure in mac

Tags: macos, cp

How to copy files from one directory to another while preserving the directory structure in mac?

I found that you can use `cp --parents` [in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209430/copy-file-to-backup-directory-preserving-folder-structure) but unfortunately that doesn't work in mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using `rsync -R` to solve this.

Comment: I had to use `rsync -Rr`: `-R` for relative path names, and `-r` for recursive descent into subdirectories. (Which, of course, only matters if you want directories rather than specifically-selected files.)

Answer (score 6):

On OS X you can use `ditto <source> <destination>`

See here: 
http://osxdaily.com/2014/06/11/use-ditto-copy-files-directories-mac-command-line/

Comment: Thanks, this worked better than `rsync -R` for copying a single file with path to another single file with path preserved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm tired of writing this manually, so I'm going to provide a non rsync way for future reference.

```
#!/bin/bash
cpParents() {
    src=(${*: 1:-1})
    dest=${*: -1:1}
    for filename in $src; do
        [ -e "$filename" ] || continue
        dirPath=$(dirname "${filename}")
        mkdir -p $dest/$dirPath
        cp $filename $dest/$dirPath
    done
}
```

Comment: If there was an equivalent of SO gold, I would give it to you. Thanks so much for this answer.